PySpark Structured Streaming Windowed Aggregation Forward Fill
Setup
The following self-contained Python script computes 15-min averages for each tag within 15-min rolling windows.
# Python built-in
import tempfile
from datetime import datetime

# Third-party
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import window, col, avg
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType,
    StructField,
    StringType,
    TimestampType,
)

SCHEMA = StructType([
    StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("tag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
ROWS = [
    Row(timestamp=datetime(year=2023, month=12, day=30, hour=0, minute=37),
        tag="A",
        value="2.8"),
    Row(timestamp=datetime(year=2023, month=12, day=30, hour=0, minute=37),
        tag="B",
        value="9.0"),
    Row(timestamp=datetime(year=2023, month=12, day=30, hour=0, minute=38),
        tag="B",
        value="7.4"),
    Row(timestamp=datetime(year=2023, month=12, day=30, hour=0, minute=47),
        tag="A",
        value="3.2"),
    Row(timestamp=datetime(year=2023, month=12, day=30, hour=0, minute=48),
        tag="A",
        value="1.8"),
]

spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .appName("structured streaming windowed aggregation")
         .getOrCreate()
)

# Suppress most log messages
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:

    # Write input data to JSON file to be stream read
    df = spark.createDataFrame(ROWS, SCHEMA)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show()
    df.write.mode('overwrite').format('json').save(d)

    # Stream read the data
    df_streaming = (
        spark.readStream
        .format('json')
        .schema(SCHEMA)
        .load(d)
    )

    # Compute 15min avg per tag
    df_windowed_average = (
        df_streaming
        .withWatermark("timestamp", '0 minutes')
        .groupBy(window("timestamp", '15 minutes'), col("tag"))
        .agg(avg("value").alias("avg"))
        .orderBy("window", "tag")
    )

    # Print result to terminal (takes 12 seconds on my MacBook Pro)
    query = (
        df_windowed_average.writeStream
        .format('console')
        .outputMode('complete')
        .trigger(once=True)
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()
    )

Execute the script:
spark-submit <module-name>.py

Output:
+-------------------+---+-----+
|          timestamp|tag|value|
+-------------------+---+-----+
|2023-12-30 00:17:00|  A|  2.8|
|2023-12-30 00:17:00|  B|  9.0|
|2023-12-30 00:18:00|  B|  7.4|
|2023-12-30 00:31:00|  A|  3.2|
|2023-12-30 00:32:00|  A|  1.8|
+-------------------+---+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+---+---+
|              window|tag|avg|
+--------------------+---+---+
|{2023-12-30 00:15...|  A|2.8|
|{2023-12-30 00:15...|  B|8.2|
|{2023-12-30 00:30...|  A|2.5|
+--------------------+---+---+

Problem
Because no data for tag B was present in the second 15-min window [00:30:00, 00:45:00), no average for B exists in the output table for that window.
I would like to use the average value 8.2 from the previous 15-min window [00:15:00, 00:30:00) to fill the missing average.
